# Facing an issue in downloading a file from remote server

Tags: php, file, remote-access

I am trying to download a file from remote server. I have searched and got the below code. It is not working. It gives me a corrupted file even though the URL & file name are correct. This is my code,

```
    $file = $URL.$filename;

    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $r;
```

I don't know what is the problem. Also, i haven't worked in Remote server file download.

Can anyone help me to debug this or is there any better script to download a file?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Refer this - http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php

Comment: @ejo No. But i am getting corrupted file.

Comment: are you able to save the file your getting remotely to the local filesystem and verify that the file isn't corrupted already from that process?  It may have nothing to do with the download part.

Comment: im not sure, but.. just try two things.  
1. use `trim` `$r = trim( curl_exec( $ch ) );`  
2. add an `exit();` after `echo $r;`

Comment: and can you give an example link which you were trying to download?

Comment: @bystwn22 It is not working

Comment: @EdwinAlex so can you give me an example link?